# Add Overall X-Axis Descriptor to bottom of Pyplot Subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following plot:

[image]

And I need to place some text on the "overall" x-axis--such that the description clearly applies to the x-axis of each of the three graphs along the column.

How do I access the label for the x axis of the table holding the subplots? (or whichever object is applicable here).

I created the graphs using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f,(ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3, sharey=True)

#plotted my stuff
....

#now: how to add general label to entire subplot
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a big sub-figure (say 'sub') and give a x-label to it . The three other figures (sub1, sub2, sub3) can be added as secondary sub-figures within the first. Now if a x-label is applied to the original big sub-figure 'sub', it appears as a common x-label to all the three figures. You can however add different y-labels to the three figures seperately. A sample program showing the same thing is given below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0.01,10,100)
y1 = x
y2 = np.log(x)
y3 = np.exp(x)

fig = plt.figure()
sub = fig.add_subplot(111)
sub1 = fig.add_subplot(131)
sub2 = fig.add_subplot(132)
sub3 = fig.add_subplot(133)

sub1.plot(x, y1)
sub2.plot(x, y2)
sub3.plot(x, y3)

sub.set_xlabel('functions of x')
sub1.set_ylabel('$y=x$')
sub2.set_ylabel('$y=sin(x)$')
sub3.set_ylabel('$y=e^x$')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `fig.text`. Something like:

```
fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'My xlabel text', ha='center', va='bottom')
```